# How to connect to the remote server using curl and php through proxy?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

How to connect to the remote server usinbg curl and php thru proxy?

Answer (score 3):

PHP libcurl supports proxy settings:

`curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy)`